# NULL Values from SQL to R

Tags: r, null

I have a Csv exported from SQL which looks like:

[image]

I want to remove all the rows that contain NULL in any column.
I've tried :

```
x = read.csv("TimeLog1.csv",header=TRUE)
x[is_empty(x)] = NA 
x <- x[complete.cases(x), ]
```

Both the latter lines don't work. It still returns the complete Dataframe.

When I do:

```
is.null(x)
```

It returns FALSE.

Desired Output will contain only the 4th and 5th Row in my Dataframe X.

Comment: Please check the `str(x)`  Either the `NULL` would be string `"NULL"` or the column is a `list` column.  Also, checking `is.null(x)` is on the whole dataset and not in each column.  For that you may need to loop over the columns.  You can't have `NULL` on a vector

Comment: 'data.frame': 19 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ Name: Factor w/ 1 level "Jibran": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Date: Factor w/ 19 levels "4/16/2015","4/17/2015",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    10 ...
    $ In  : Factor w/ 13 levels "4/16/2015 20:10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 13 13 13 13 6 ...
    $ Out : Factor w/ 15 levels "4/22/2015 1:01",..: 15 15 15 1 2 3 4 5 6 15 ... @akrun

Comment: Can you show the `levels(x$In)`

Comment: Its a String "NULL" @akrun

Comment: In that case, do `levels(x$In)[levels(x$In) == "NULL"] <- NA`

Comment: Works a charm, Thank you @akrun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a string (`"NULL"`) and the column is `factor`, assign the `levels` that are `"NULL"` to `NA` and then use `is.na` or `complete.cases`

```
levels(x$In)[levels(x$In) == "NULL"] <- NA
```

---

For multiple columns, we use `lapply`

```
x[c("In", "Out")] <- lapply(x[c("In", "Out")], function(y) {
                   levels(y)[levels(y) == "NULL"] <- NA
                    y
                    })
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple Base R solution will be . add Null to the na.strings while importing the file.

```
x<- read.csv("stack_null.csv", na.strings=c("NULL"))
str(x)
x_null1 <- na.omit(x)
```

this will make your task easy and fast.